# Serial port communication

Tags: 20.04, serial-port

I am trying to communicate with an HP48SX calculator over serial interface with C-Kermit and am getting an error message when trying to set the parameters to be compatible with the HP. Using Ubuntu 20.04LTS on a Dell Inspiron 17R. The message is:

```
Sorry, write access to UUCP lockfile directory denied
```

I can find no lockfiles on my system nor any reference to UUCP. The USB-to-DB9 adapter is recognized as ttyUSB0. I have searched with Google and tried various fixes offered there to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using a serial cable thru USB as we don't have RS-232 anymore which was the old way to do this under Windows. I have downloaded and compiled C-Kermit which created the necessary software to do this. There are various parameters that need to be set so the calculator can respond. Here they are :

```
./wermit                ; Start C-Kermit
; The following commands are entered at the "C-Kermit>" prompt...
set port /dev/ttyUSB0
set speed 9600          ; Serial port speed, HP48 defaults to 9600, also supports 4800 2400 1200
set carrier-watch off   ; It's not a modem connection so ignore carrier signal state.
set modem type none     ; No modem is involved; don't send AT commands.
set flow none           ; Flow control is not supported by HP48.
set parity none         ; 8 data bits, no parity
set control prefix all  ; HP48 Kermit requires all control characters to be encoded in printable form.
set file type binary    ; Might not always be needed.*
```

As soon as I try to enter any of these 'set' commands, I get the message I listed above. On the C-Kermit website, there are all the necessary instructions and the author did this on his machine with no problems so I think it is something missing in my Ubnutu 20.04 installation.

Comment: Did you add your user to the `dialout` group?

Comment: You have not given much detail of *how* you are trying to connect. The more you tell us, the more we can help.